# Breeze doesn't fill one-to-many navigation property with optional inverse property

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I have the following classes:

```
public class SalesProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Image> ProductImages { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? SalesProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual SalesProduct SalesProduct { get; set; }
}
```

and the Fluent API configuration for SalesProduct:

```
HasMany(x => x.ProductImages)
    .WithOptional(x => x.SalesProduct)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.SalesProductId);
```

`SalesProduct` has the `ProductImages` collection and EF sends it to the frontend, but Breeze doesn't fill it (it has length 0). Should it work? Am I missing something?

Edit: The relation is loaded using eager  loading in backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work! It started to work after a while without taking any actions.

Answer (score 0):

`ProductImages` needs to be marked as `virtual` as well for EF to lazily load related entities

```
public virtual ICollection<Image> ProductImages { get; set; }
```

Comment: The relation is loaded using eager loading.